# Nuget pack csproj with dependencies on other csproj

Tags: nuget, tfsbuild, nuget-spec

I have two projects

1. A.csproj
2. B.csproj

where B references A (reference to project in solution)

**I want to automate creation of packages, where package B will contain dependecy to package A**

I've generated nuspec using `nuget spec A.csproj` and created package using `nuget pack A.csproj`. The same for project B.

however B.nuspec does not contain dependecy to nuget package A?

I want to automate creation of nuget packages on TFS build server, where assembly version is determined at build time.

In package B, how to add dependency to package A with correct version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, to add the referenced projects as part of the package, you need to use the **IncludeReferencedProjects** option. 
The command line is something like "nuget pack A.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects"

Secondly, as you want to create NuGet packages during TFS build process, you need to create one PowerShell script which is similar to the followings, and include the PowerShell script in the Pre-build script (Assume you're using TFS2013 or TFS2015).

```
$projectFile = "project.csproj"
$nugetPath = “NuGet.exe"
$version = $Env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
Write-Host ("packing $projectFile...")
& $nugetPath pack "$projectFile" -Version $version -Symbols -IncludeReferencedProjects
```